# Connect via TCP and public IP without forwarding

Tags: java, tcp, ip, public, forwarding

I'm trying to write a simple chat program using TCP in java.

To connect to a server I need to know its IP address. I'm connected to a router in my network, that connects me to the Internet.

When I type local IP (assigned by router) it works pretty well between my two computers.
But when I typed public IP (I got it from google: "what is your ip"...) - it didn't work.

So I opened router's setup and make forwarding rule from my public IP and specific port to the local IP - and it worked.

--------- Question:
But how to do this **without forwarding**? I want to write a chat program. I can't tell my users: "just do the port forwarding" ;)
One opens my program and logs into central server, then writes there public IP. Some other user opens this server, download the file and gets first user's IP (or any other needed info).
But if first user didn't do the port forwarding, it won't work. How to make it work?

Comment: You can't. The public IP address is that of the router. The server isn't running in the router. Without port forwarding, it can't work. That's what port forwarding is for.

Comment: So how about other protocol then TCP.
Like you have for instance FTP. I connect to a server and download a file to my PC, and that server knows somehow my local IP (or some way to it) so the file gets to my computer. How it's done?

Comment: Your question is kinda unclear. Took me a while to figure out you don't want your **USERS** to port forward their routers!

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to understand how something called NAT (network address translation) works. In simple terms the NAT is responsible for sending packets to the right computer on the internal network from the external.

Say for example you have computer A as a server on the internal network, and have computer B on the external. If you then try to connect to computer A from computer B, it will not work because NAT (your router) doesent know what computer to send that packet of data to, on the internal network.

Its diffrent when you want to connect to an external server. Lets say computer A (client) is on the external network, and computer B (server) is on the internal network with the router port forwarded to its IP-address. Then you will be able to connect to the server because NAT knows where to send the data packets.

> **So to keep all your users from port forwarding their routers:**
>
> - Port forward your server on your internal network
> - Connect the clients on another network
> - For clients on the internal network; use the local IP of the server

Hope this helped!
-Kad

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly solution.
I can't port forward server or client - cos both TCP server&client are some users who want to chat- I don't have access to their routers.

But can you explain me something? Lets say I want to chat to my friend Ben.   
My PC -> ROUTER 1 -> Internet <- ROUTER 2 <- Ben's PC.   

I made a port forwarding on my ROUTER 1 and place a TCP server on "My PC". Ben's writing to my public IP (router 1's IP). So his text goes into ROUTER 1 and it port forward it to "My PC".
But now I respond to Ben (I check it in real). So how does the ROUTER 2 know the path to Ben?

Comment: There is a way to not do any port forwarding, but includes your user to connect to your local network using a VPN tunnel. Look up a program called Hamachi for this, since it is the simplest to use.
<br><br>
For your other question: 
Your friends router remembers where it has sent information, and where it has came from. So lets say your friend connects to your server. Then your friends router knows it has sendt some packets to that server, and when it gets a response, it looks at it and determines it came from your friends computer.

Comment: Thank you. I decided I will use mysql on central server and use it in Java, so it won't be necessary for users to do anything ;)